# Many database calls that load less data or fewer database calls that load more data?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, performance

I have a website I'm working on that loads 8 rows of data by making an AJAX call to a PHP content loader that calls my database each time the user hits a next button to load the new content.

This method works very fast for me right now as a single user of the site.

My question is though, if I have many users on the site, would it be better to load the next 16,32, etc rows of data up front when they hit next or keep the way it is now by loading in 8 rows each time they hit next? Does it matter?

Comment: for any average site it will make no difference.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to truly answer this question is with load testing, and some judgement calls. What is the additional database overhead to load more rows? Are you constrained on database processing power, or bandwidth to your web server? Does loading additional rows enhance the user experience, regardless of server performance?

You will need to answer these types of questions when making your decision, but ultimately it is determined by the specifics of the queries, data, and functionality of your site.